# Changing subview content after view has loaded (cocoa touch)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk

I am trying to create my own implementation of a tab bar, using a toolbar instead of a tabbar (to enable customization of the new "tab bar").  In order to achieve this, I need to have the ability to switch between views when a button is pressed.

Currently, my view consists of a tabBar subview, and a customView subview.  The latter needs to be switched in the button callback of newTabBarController.  Can anyone tell me how I might do this?  Essentially I am wanting the same effect as presentModalViewController for the subview.  Simply setting my view pointer to a different view doesn't work.

Here is some example code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  customView = selectedViewController.view;
  [self.view addSubView:customView];
  [self.view addSubView:newTabBarController.view];
}

- (void)buttonHandler:(id)sender {
  NewViewController newController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
  // what to do now??
}
```

To be clear:  the newTabBarController does not inherit from UITabBarController.  It subclasses UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on keeping those views around, I'd add them all to the superview and use bringSubviewToFront: and sendSubviewToBack: to manage which one the user sees.

```
//what to do now??
[self.view addSubView:newController.view];
[customView sendSubviewToBack];
```

From the iPhone Application Programming Guide:

> To reorder existing subviews inside their parent, call the bringSubviewToFront:, sendSubviewToBack:, or exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex: methods of the parent view. Using these methods is faster than removing the subviews and reinserting them.

Comment: Thanks, this solution will suffice for now.  I can't help but feel that a UINavigationController should be used here.